# Can I write $[x_{i,j}]$ for the matrix whose $\{i,j\}$-th element is $x_{i,j}$?

Tags: matrices, notation

Is it a general way to write $[x_{i,j}]$ for the matrix whose $\{i,j\}$-th element is $x_{i,j}$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this notation used (sometimes with "()" rather than "[]"), and I would think that most people reading any linear algebra text would know what you mean.

If you want to be more explicit, you could right something like $X = [x_{ij}]_{i,j = 1}^n$ to mean "let $X$ denote the matrix whose entries are $x_{ij}$ where $i$ and $j$ go from $1$ to $n$".